# Is it possible to change virtual desktop with right+left mouse buttons and mouse direction?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, virtualdesktop, workflow

I have just upgraded my Kubuntu to 20.04 and looks great up up until now.

I was wondering if it's possible to change a virtual desktop env using both right+left mouse buttons and a mouse direction to define up/down/left/right (or to an opposite direction, like a "drag"). I used to do that with the very old Ubuntus (when compiz fusion was still a thing and the cube was mind blowing).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it with:

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/j8tppi/is_it_possible_to_change_virtual_desktop_with/

tl;dr:

1. systemsettings->Shortcuts->Own shortcuts: Make sure"Gestures" are
   enabled and that the "mousebutton" is set to the one you want to use
2. Inside "own shortcuts" make a new Group (Edit -> New group)
3. If you want to can make some conditions for the new group like only
   applying if done above the empty desktop
4. Add a new mouse-gesture/dbus-call to the group
5. Modify the ""trigger" to have the gesture you want (moving mouse
   let/right/up/down..whatever)
6. in "action" set:

   - org.kde.kglobalaccel
   - /component/kwin
   - org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut
   - "Switch One Desktop Down"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. In System Settings, type `short` into the filter field above the left panel, then select Global Shortcuts. Scroll down the list of applications to find `kwin` and type 'switch' into the second filter field below the Global Shortcuts heading. There you can choose to add your custom shortcut to any of the desktop switches listed.

Comment: Hi, So this is what i was trying to do but it doesn't allow me to use any mouse key bindings, and was wondering if there is something I'm missing in the whole process..